# Delay in UINavigationBar Appearance Effect

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

[image: Gif of the effect]

Background: my app uses Firebase as a backend, listens for state changes to the current user, and, when logged in, sets the above controller as the root view controller. It is a **`UITabBarController` that contains several `UINavigationControllers`**. Well before it is presented, I style the navigation bar via `UINavigationBar.appearance()`. I notice two things from the loading behavior:

- The bar loads after the contained content.
- You can see the dividing line that would appear from an un-styled navigation bar, which leads me to believe that the default appearance has some sort of delay.

Has anyone experienced something like this? My goal is to have the controller fully load at once, and ideally not see the divider line.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Appearance.shared.configure() // All UINavigationBar-related styling

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    configureFirebase() // Listens for FIRAuth change, then sets window.rootViewController = MyTabBarController()
    return true
}
```

Comment: put some relevant code to how you present the viewcontroller after users log in

Comment: Added. I'm just re-setting `window.rootViewController` once logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `UINavigationBar.appearance()` code into the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of your `AppDelegate`.